# Php echo, clearing my surrounding html?

Tags: php, echo

I am working on a site for class, and i have a form system. My friend is working on the design, and therefore the index site is actually just this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Nail n' Bolts man</title>
<link href="../../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">
        <center>
            <div id="header">
                Nails & Bolts APS - Admin side
                <img src="../images/header.jpg" alt="header" width="" height="" />
            </div>

            <?php require('php/newEmployee.php'); ?>
        </center>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in newEmployee.php i also require another file called varibleEcho.php Basically this file just has a function with a switch case statement, echoing different code depending on what you call from newEmployee.php

however for some reason, when i check the source of the site with google chrome, it seems that the echoing cleans everything of except the stuff i echo. This means my metadata css jquery and such dissapers.

Any ideas on why it has this behaviour?

Edit:

Here is the entire site (indes.php up there):

**newEmployee.php**

```
<?php
require('php/variableEcho.php');
    if(!isset($_POST['rank']) || !isset($_POST['fname']) || !isset($_POST['lname']) || !isset($_POST['initials']))
    {
        variableEcho(0);
        variableEcho(1);    
    }
    else if($_POST['rank'] == '' || $_POST['fname'] == '' || $_POST['lname'] == '' || $_POST['initials'] == '')
    {
        variableEcho(0);
        variableEcho(3);
        variableEcho(1);
    }
        else if($_POST['password'] != '')
    {
    echo $_POST['password'];
    $hasLetter = false;
    $hasNumber = false;
    $hasLength = false;

    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    $strlen = strlen($pwd);
    $pwdarr = str_split($pwd);

    $ints = 0;
    $chars = 0;
    foreach($pwdarr as $x)
    {
        if(is_int($x))
        {
            $ints++;
        }
        if(ctype_alpha($x))
        {
            $chars++;
        }
    }
    if($ints >= $strlen || $chars >= $strlen)
    {
        variableEcho(0);
        variableEcho(4);
        variableEcho(1);
    }

    if($strlen >= 8)
    {
        variableEcho(0);
        variableEcho(4);
        variableEcho(1);
    }
}
?>
```

**variableEcho**

```
<?php
function variableEcho($echoSelect)
{
    switch($echoSelect)
    {
        case 0:
            echo('
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <table>
            ');
            break;

        case 1:
            echo('
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="fname">First name*</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="lname">Last name*</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="rank">Rank*</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="rank" id="rank"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="initials">Initials (3 length)*</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="initials" id="initials"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit"/></td>
                    </form>
            ');
            break;

        case 2:
            echo('
                        <tr>
                            <td><div class="errText">A password is required for admins.</div></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
            ');
            break;

        case 3:
            echo('
                        <tr>
                            <td><div class="errText">Please fill out all the obligatory fields.</div></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
            ');

        case 4:
            echo('
                        <tr>
                            <td><div class="errText">The password need to be of atleas one letter, one number, and 8 long.</div></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

            ');
            break;

        default:
            echo('
                biscuit
            ');
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't know what could be causing it but you can troubleshoot by removing most of the code (and verify the problem no longer happens) and slowly adding in bits until the problem comes back. Also, you don't have a break in case 3. You don't need a break in default case.

Comment: i am assuming the problem happens after someone submits the form, if so check what is the URL in the browser and make sure it is what its supposed to be, you left the `action` attribute empty on your form

Comment: Action is empty, as it should send to itself. I echo different things to the site, depending on the input, therefore also on the default site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, and it was sadly a simple one :P

require 'newEmployee.php';

would include that php file. In that file i required another one, where the filepath were relative to newEmployee.php locaiton. I now instead include both variableEcho, and newEmployee from the main file.

```
<?php
    require('../../php/variableEcho.php');
    require('../../php/newEmployee.php');               
?>
```